# Populate Listview with images from device low performance

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm using a listview with adapter. Also i'm populate Listview with images from my device. The problem is that every time i'm scrolling listview it looks like it stack for a while till to load next images. It doesnt scrolling like wind!

Here is my adapter:

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {

        DataViewHolder holder = null;

        var view = convertView;
        if (view != null)
        {
            holder = view.Tag as DataViewHolder;
        }

        if (holder == null)
        {
            view = LayoutInflater.From(mContext).Inflate(Resource.Layout.CatalogCategories, null, false);

            holder = new DataViewHolder();

            holder.txtCategoryName = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtCategoryName);
            holder.txtCategoryID = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtCategoryID);
            holder.imageview1 = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.CategoryImageView);

            view.Tag = holder;
        }

        holder.txtCategoryName.Text = mitems[position].CategoryName;
        holder.txtCategoryID.Text = mitems[position].CategoryID;

        //Starting To read image from device
        var sdcardPath = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.Path;
        var imageFilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(sdcardPath, "dbsoft/" + holder.txtCategoryName.Text + ".jpg");//Φάκελος και εικόνα

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(imageFilePath))
        {

            var imageFile = new Java.IO.File(imageFilePath);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(imageFile.AbsolutePath);
            holder.imageview1.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }

        return view;
    }
    public class DataViewHolder : Java.Lang.Object
    {
        public TextView txtCategoryName { get; set; }
        public TextView txtCategoryID { get; set; }
        public ImageView imageview1 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to keep images that have already be shown? So to not load them every time i scroll up or down my listview?

Also if i will try it doesnt work neither:

```
if(imageview1==null)
{
//read image from sd
}
```

Comment: Wait. Java? C#? It surely can't be both, and you really don't want to mistag your question.

Comment: I'm guessing that this is truly a C# question, with the `get; set;` syntax, but again, it is in your best interest to correct your tags.

Comment: I suggest putting the image loading in thread and either 1) do not allow scrolling past what is loaded or 2) show a place holder until the image is loaded.   This will allow smooth scrolling which images are loaded, which is very byte intensive

Comment: I'm writing with xamarin-C# but its simulately with java.Should i untag java?

Comment: Tagging wrongly brings the experts of a different language to look at your question. They will not be happy with you

Comment: @ tatmanblue putting image in thread helped a lot! but what do you mean by 1) do not allow scrolling past what is loaded or 2) show a place holder until the image is loaded. Can you give me an example?

Comment: Any help please?

Comment: If you haven't already, compress the images to a size which fits the size needed for your `ListView`. This will **greatly** increase performance. if you tap the image to show it in full screen for example, you can still show the full-sized image in a new page.

Comment: I think that in my code reloads images every time i'm scrolling up or down. I need to keep images which have already be reloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are blocking the UI thread by calling `BitmapFactory.DecodeFile` in `GetView`. You will want to do that on a separate thread.

To help you doing so, you could use FFImageLoading, Picasa or some other library which handles these things very nicely.

Otherwise, you will need to offload the work to another thread. Keeping the images in memory won't work as you will run out of memory very fast. Especially if these images are large in size.

Also instead of using `ListView` use a `RecyclerView`, this way you can easily know when a cell is attached/detached to start/stop loading images. Meaning you can cancel any image loading operations if the cell it was loading for goes off screen.

Comment: Thank you for your answers my problem solved with picasso. Just three lines code and problem has been solved!